# How to find the sum of numbers between 20 and 30 in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to find the sum of numbers between 20 and 30 in oracle using select statement

Comment: Did you try searching the Internet before you posted your question? Does this help? [To find the sum of all odd no between 1 and 20 from dual](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1865647/to-find-the-sum-of-all-odd-no-between-1-and-20-from-dual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the numbers:

```sql
SELECT 20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30 AS total FROM DUAL
```

Or, calculate the total:

```sql
SELECT (:range_start + :range_end)/2 * (:range_end - :range_start + 1) AS total FROM DUAL
```

which, with the hard-coded values would be:

```sql
SELECT (20 + 30)/2 * (30 - 20 + 1) AS total FROM DUAL
```

Or, use a hierarchical query to generate rows and sum them:

```sql
SELECT SUM(20 + (LEVEL - 1)) AS total FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 11
```

Or, use a recursive query to generate rows and sum them:

```sql
WITH data (value) AS (
  SELECT 20 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT value + 1 FROM data WHERE value < 30
)
SELECT SUM(value) AS total FROM data
```

Or, use a PL/SQL loop:

```sql
DECLARE
  total NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 20 .. 30 LOOP
    total := total + i;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(total);
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=120417ea5be4bc3b1c5d503ecd8c946c)*

Comment: Yes but I don't want to add the numbers manually like (20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30) when I pass the number oracle itself do the work and return the value.

Comment: @shajin That requirement is not part of the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
with one_to_twenty as (            
      select 
            rownum ints
      from 
            dual 
      connect by rownum <= 20
      )


select 
     sum(ints)
from
     one_to_twenty  
where 
     ints > 10
```

`one_to_twenty` generates a range of numbers, 10 to 20, and the subselect sums the values starting from 10.